# Leia's death and Jedi funerals

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Is there an in-universe reason why when Leia died she wasn't given a traditional Jedi funeral (cremation)?

Comment: Was Leia a Jedi? Granted she could use the force but does that make her a Jedi?

Comment: @Paulie_D she was, as shown in Episode IX.

Comment: training as a Jedi does not mean one is a Jedi...from a certain point of view. Ashoka says as much in S2 of Star Wars Rebels "Shroud of Darkness": 'Because I am no longer a Jedi. It was my choice, I left the Order. '

Comment: "When you're a Jedi, you're a Jedi all the way
From your first cigaredi to your last dying day."
_West Sith Story_

Comment: Maybe Leia didn't want a Jedi funeral? For instance, she may have felt a traditional Alderaanian service would be more fitting, considering her life and circumstances.

Comment: Probably it was not a proper time for a funeral (when the fate of the Galaxy was in balance), and later she became One with The Force, thus no body to bury.

Comment: Just like Assange Ventress was never a Sith, Leia was never a Jedi. To be a Jedi, you have to complete your training. Ashoka never did that is why she is not a Jedi. To remain a Jedi, you must uphold the Jedi ways. The ones who gave up are known as dark Jedis.

Comment: [Extremely related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147449/58193) to the point of being a dupe.

Comment: It could be a moot point soon anyway. I was reading that Disney are possibly considering striking the sequel triology from canon

Answer (score 2):

Leia specifically chose *not* to be a Jedi because she sensed doing so would lead to the death of her son, as [explained by Luke in *The Rise of Skywalker*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJrd6cyN8rw):

> "It was the last night of her training. Leia told me that she had sensed the death of her son at the end of her Jedi path. She surrendered her saber to me and said one day it would be picked up again by someone who would finish her journey."

As such, there's no reason she would be given a Jedi funeral (and doing so would likely have been disrespectful of her wishes).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: she wasn't a Jedi. Although she was trained to use a lightsaber, she had no Jedi master, she was not trained to use the force, and she had a husband and a family. (which is forbidden for Jedi) The Jedi ceremony is probably reserved for Jedi only. Lightsaber training and relation to a Jedi does not make her a Jedi.

Comment: The rules might be different for the new Jedi order

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Especially considering that that specific rule was one of the direct causes of the destruction of the old order.  It's the sort of thing that might lead you to re-examine the premise on which the rule was based...